# Using "reduction" in a title

Tags: meaning, word-choice

I am writing a paper where I will use the title *Reduction by half*. This is supposed to describe a method which reduces something by half, but I am not sure if *Reduction by Half* is the right way to do this. Any ideas? Does *Reduction by Half* sound weird?

Comment: What is the goal of this method? Are you proposing a method by which the number of members in a set may be reduced by a half, or are you reducing the number by in order to accomplish something else? If the latter, is the reduction arbitrary or there is some principle at work determining which members are removed?

Comment: It's the latter and there is a principle

Comment: If the principle is an important element of your method and not offered as a mere example, it seems to me that it should be at least part of the method name. For instance, if the principle is removing every other member, something like "Reduction by Alternation (RA)" or "Halving by Alternation (HA)" would be called for.

Comment: I think I will simply call it *Halving Method*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may be less awkward to refer to it as the "[*halving*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/halving) method".

> to reduce to one half, "*halving* the present cost"

Comment: +1 *To halve* is one of my favorite verbs, right up there with *to wolve*.

Answer (score 3):

"Does reduction by half sound weird ?"

No and yes (This sounds weird). No because it's typical of academic prose: probably verbose (but we can't know that without seeing the entire title). Yes because it's an unnecessary transmogrification (a beautifully weird word) of a verb into a noun.

How about saying something like "X reduces cost of producing Y by half" or "X reduces by half cost of producing Y"? You're probably introducing a new method or a new ingredient for a technical process. The first words of the title should indicate that, e.g., "Aluminum [the new ingredient] reduces weight of fishing sinkers by half" and "Eliminating unnecessary tests reduces medical costs by half".

I don't know if this is helpful because it's really necessary to see how you're planning to structure the entire title of the paper, not just three words of it. Can you give us an idea of what you're thinking of saying without revealing what you reasonably want to keep secret until the paper is published?

Comment: I am basically trying to give the method a brief name. There are various methods that does a reduction on a set of numbers (they remove some amount of numbers from it). and this particular one takes out half of the numbers from the set. So that's basically why I want to call method (and the title) Reduction by Half as the section will talk about it :) Let me know if you have further questions

Comment: I also want to be able to refer this method later with its name such as "However, the reduction by half method achieves better results" so this is why I want to stick to this name

Comment: @Cemre It may be less awkward to refer to it as the "[*halving*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/halving) method".

Comment: It sounds fine to me as the name of a technique. Not at all weird. Better than "50% off". :-) I'd write it "the Reduction by Half method": it's a proper name. I don't think that "the halving method" sounds anywhere near as good as "the Reduction by Half method".

Comment: @BillFranke To each his own. It sounds like its use has already been cemented in the paper. Nevertheless, for brevity, it could be abbreviated after its first introduction: i.e. "the Reduction by Half (RbH) method". This is common practice from what I've seen. Some recent examples include the [LQG method](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1208.6064.pdf) and [NM method](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1208.6119.pdf).

Comment: Yes, "to each his own". I like "the RbH method" too. Good suggestion. Most questions about English usage are about personal preferences, not correct grammar or standard usages. Language is an art for those who don't mathematize it, quantify it, or use it to speak to machines. The major differences between R2D2 and C3PO are strictly style. The former is incomprehensible to normal humans, and the latter is a concession to the human (especially _cat-loving_ human) need to anthropomorphize everything we see.

Comment: I do all those things to some degree and still consider language an art. W-w-wait. . . cir-c-cuits overl-l-loading ERROR ERR--

Comment: I should have added "exclusively". Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: @Zairja and Bill Franke thanks so much for all suggestions I am actually in between the halving and reduction by half so I Will try to think about it a bit more and then decide. I am usually very picky about word choices and naming so it's takes time to decide :) Thanks again !

Answer (score 2):

*Reduction by half* is alright but incomplete. The title should be something like *Reduction of mosquitoes by half using insecticide*.

Comment: Thanks but since this is going to be name of a technique (and the title will be that name since the section will talk about this method) I want something brief to call this method. That's why I am considering Reduction by Half.

Answer (score 2):

Since it's the title of a paper, you could trot out the Latin, and call the technique

> *reductio ad dimidium*

which literally means *reduction to half*.

If you Google the phrase, it turns up a couple of mathematical techniques that appear to do exactly that.

Comment: That technique would be RAD! :)